# clicking on the child image link goes to the parent background image link

Tags: jquery, css

I have this page:
http://test.actful.com/demo/actfulhome-hovertile2.html

we have tiled images on this page, and on hover there are a few icons that are displayed on each tile. there is a link for the background, and each icon has it's own link (currently just "#"), the link for the background opens up a modal and displays a page. currently when I click on the icons the background link is effective and the modal opens up. I dont want the background link to take effect when the link on the icon is clicked. how do I achieve this.
I tried setting a low z-index property for the background and a higher z-index property for the icons, but that did not solve the issue. 
How can I resolve this issue?

You could view the source for the html page but let me be a little more specific

Here is the code for each tile:

```
    <div class="contenthover actfulModalButton">
                  <div>
                    <div class="four columns icon-align-center align-left"><a class="tile-icon-link" href="#"><img class="tile-icon-images" src="images/ActfulIcons_ActfulFBIcon.svg" alt="Face Book"/></a></div>
                    <div class="four columns icon-align-center align-center"><a class="tile-icon-link" href="#"><img class="tile-icon-images" src="images/ActfulIcons_ActfulKangarooIcon.svg" alt="Actit"/></a></div>
                    <div class="four columns icon-align-center align-right"><a class="tile-icon-link" href="#"><img class="tile-icon-images" src="images/ActfulIcons_actfulCommentsIcon.svg" alt="Comments"/></a></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="button-bottom">
                    <button data-act-itemid="100" class="small button actfulModalButton">View Details</button> 
                  </div>
                </div>
```

The jquery following jquery code at the bottom creates a link for  "actfulModalButton" (parent background div) on page load :

```
     $(".actfulModalButton").click(function() {      
     var itemid = $(this).attr('data-act-itemid');
     $("#actItemFrame").attr('src', 'actful-item-details.html?actitemid='+itemid);
     $("#actItemModal").reveal();   
   });
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add some code here so we can see what's going on

Comment: sorry about that, I have added bit of code for each tile. since it is plain HTML, CSS and Jquery, you could also view source for the code. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".actfulModalButton").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // this code will prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
  var itemid = $(this).attr('data-act-itemid');
  $("#actItemFrame").attr('src', 'actful-item-details.html?actitemid='+itemid);
  $("#actItemModal").reveal();   
});
```

**[update]**

I now understand what you want.

You just need add the following, and keep your code unchange:

```
$(".actfulModalButton a.tile-icon-link").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation(); // this code will prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event. 
});
```

Comment: I tried adding event.stopPropagation(); but then that completely disabled the link, I just dont want it the link to work when the icons are clicked, otherwise the link should work.